# How to avoid time-gaps in matplotlib when plotting time series whose index is sparse?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Lets say I have a pd.Series whose index has 1 minute frequency and it is only active on hour 9 each day.

```
    df = pd.util.testing.makeTimeDataFrame(nper = 10000, freq = 'min')['A']
    df = df[df.index.hour == 9]
    df.plot()
```

If I plot this using `df.plot()`. I get this ugly looking plots where the last time stamps of a yesterday is connected the first timestamps of today as follow:

[image]

Is there a way to remove the long daily gaps and connect the end of yesterday to the beginning of today in the plot, or remove the connecting line between the days.